# Upgrade from Bootstrap 3.1.0 to 3.3.7

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am thinking about upgrading the bootstrap files for my site.  Is there any major changes in classes that I need to be aware of or is going to be mostly just a plug and play situation?  The site has about 200 pages and I'm hoping that it is just a matter of updating the files.

Comment: check this link https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/themes/bootstrap/changelog

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't face any major issue by replacing old files with new bootstrap files. Feel Free to Replace Old version with newer version. In 3.* series, bootstrap just fixed the bugs and makes very small changes in the bootstrap 3. So don't worry about this.

Comment: Thank you Usman.  I created a test server and replaced the bootstrap files on the root folder.  I then tested the functionality of the site and all is well.

Comment: This answer is wrong! Specially if you compare v3.0.1 (which is part of **3.*** as stated in the answer!) with 3.3.7.

Try to compare the CSS files with DiffMerge...